# Can I use coccinelle to change argument types in a function signature

Tags: coccinelle

I am new to coccinelle and trying to find how can I change argument types in function signatures.

I  have a function that takes a pointer of type T1 as an argument

```
int fn(T1* p)
```

I would like to change the function to take an argument of type T2 as follows

```
int fn(T2* p)
```

Can someone point me to an example that changes *argument type* . I am able to find examples to changer order and number of args.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do something similar.

```
@ change_arg_type @
identifier func;
identifier arg;
type T = int;
@@

func(...,
- T arg
+ float arg
, ...) { ... }
```

Something like that should do the trick.